# Creating PureScript records from inconsistent JavaScript objects

Tags: purescript

Assume I have User records in my PureScript code with the following type:

```
{ id        :: Number
, username  :: String
, email     :: Maybe String
, isActive  :: Boolean
}
```

A CommonJS module is derived from the PureScript code. Exported User-related functions will be called from external JavaScript code.

In the JavaScript code, a "user" may be represented as:

```
var alice = {id: 123, username: 'alice', email: 'alice@example.com', isActive: true};
```

`email` may be `null`:

```
var alice = {id: 123, username: 'alice', email: null, isActive: true};
```

`email` may be omitted:

```
var alice = {id: 123, username: 'alice', isActive: true};
```

`isActive` may be omitted, in which case it is assumed `true`:

```
var alice = {id: 123, username: 'alice'};
```

`id` is unfortunately sometimes a numeric string:

```
var alice = {id: '123', username: 'alice'};
```

The five JavaScript representations above are equivalent and should produce equivalent PureScript records.

**How do I go about writing a function which takes a JavaScript object and returns a User record?** It would use the default value for a null/omitted optional field, coerce a string `id` to a number, and throw if a required field is missing or if a value is of the wrong type.

The two approaches I can see are to use the FFI in the PureScript module or to define the conversion function in the external JavaScript code. The latter seems hairy:

```
function convert(user) {
  var rec = {};
  if (user.email == null) {
    rec.email = PS.Data_Maybe.Nothing.value;
  } else if (typeof user.email == 'string') {
    rec.email = PS.Data_Maybe.Just.create(user.email);
  } else {
    throw new TypeError('"email" must be a string or null');
  }
  // ...
}
```

I'm not sure how the FFI version would work. I haven't yet worked with effects.

I'm sorry that this question is not very clear. I don't yet have enough understanding to know exactly what it is that I want to know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've put together a solution. I'm sure much can be improved, such as changing the type of `toUser` to `Json -> Either String User` and preserving error information. Please leave a comment if you can see any ways this code could be improved. :)

This solution uses [PureScript-Argonaut](https://github.com/purescript-contrib/purescript-argonaut) in addition to a few core modules.

```
module Main
  ( User()
  , toEmail
  , toId
  , toIsActive
  , toUser
  , toUsername
  ) where

import Control.Alt ((<|>))
import Data.Argonaut ((.?), toObject)
import Data.Argonaut.Core (JNumber(), JObject(), Json())
import Data.Either (Either(..), either)
import Data.Maybe (Maybe(..))
import Global (isNaN, readFloat)

type User = { id :: Number
            , username :: String
            , email :: Maybe String
            , isActive :: Boolean
            }

hush :: forall a b. Either a b -> Maybe b
hush = either (const Nothing) Just

toId :: JObject -> Maybe Number
toId obj = fromNumber <|> fromString
  where
    fromNumber = (hush $ obj .? "id")
    fromString = (hush $ obj .? "id") >>= \s ->
      let id = readFloat s in if isNaN id then Nothing else Just id

toUsername :: JObject -> Maybe String
toUsername obj = hush $ obj .? "username"

toEmail :: JObject -> Maybe String
toEmail obj = hush $ obj .? "email"

toIsActive :: JObject -> Maybe Boolean
toIsActive obj = (hush $ obj .? "isActive") <|> Just true

toUser :: Json -> Maybe User
toUser json = do
  obj <- toObject json
  id <- toId obj
  username <- toUsername obj
  isActive <- toIsActive obj
  return { id: id
         , username: username
         , email: toEmail obj
         , isActive: isActive
         }
```

**Update:** I've made improvements to the code above based on a [gist](https://gist.github.com/benkolera/6a3622aa5c6ceb99dcf8) from Ben Kolera.

Answer (score 6):

Have you had a look at `purescript-foreign` (https://github.com/purescript/purescript-foreign)? I think that's what you're looking for here.

Comment: [examples/Objects.purs](https://github.com/purescript/purescript-foreign/blob/v0.3.0/examples/Objects.purs) seems closest to what I'm trying to do. How could I modify that example to allow `x` to be either a number or a numeric string?

Comment: One way would be to create a type like 

`data SoN = S String | N Number`

and then write an `IsForeign` instance for type `SoN` using the `<|>` operator to combine the two alternatives:

`read f = S <$> readString f <|> N <$> readNumber f`

Answer (score 2):

As gb. wrote, that is exactly what the `Foreign` data type was built for. Off the top of my head:

```
convert :: Foreign -> F User
convert f = do
  id <- f ! "id" >>= readNumber
  name <- f ! "name" >>= readString
  email <- (f ! "email" >>= readNull >>= traverse readString) <|> pure Nothing
  isActive <- (f ! "isActive" >>= readBoolean) <|> pure true
  return { id, name, email, isActive }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a little more ffi

```
module User where

import Data.Maybe
import Data.Function

foreign import data UserExternal :: *

type User =
  {
    id :: Number,
    username :: String,
    email :: Maybe String,
    isActive :: Boolean
  }

type MbUser =
  {
    id :: Maybe Number,
    username :: Maybe String,
    email :: Maybe String,
    isActive :: Maybe Boolean 
  }

foreign import toMbUserImpl """
function toMbUserImpl(nothing, just, user) {
  var result = {},
      properties = ['username', 'email', 'isActive'];

  var i, prop;
  for (i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
    prop = properties[i];
    if (user.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      result[prop] = just(user[prop]);
    } else {
      result[prop] = nothing;
    }
  }
  if (!user.hasOwnProperty('id') || isNaN(parseInt(user.id))) {
    result.id = nothing;
  } else {
    result.id = just(user.id);
  }
  return result;
}
""" :: forall a. Fn3 (Maybe a) (a -> Maybe a) UserExternal MbUser

toMbUser :: UserExternal -> MbUser
toMbUser ext = runFn3 toMbUserImpl Nothing Just ext

defaultId = 0
defaultName = "anonymous"
defaultActive = false

userFromMbUser :: MbUser -> User
userFromMbUser mbUser =
  {
    id: fromMaybe defaultId mbUser.id,
    username: fromMaybe defaultName mbUser.username,
    email: mbUser.email,
    isActive: fromMaybe defaultActive mbUser.isActive
  }

userFromExternal :: UserExternal -> User
userFromExternal ext = userFromMbUser $ toMbUser ext
```